# Datatable : Hide or unhide rows depending filter value

Tags: jquery, datatable, show-hide

I have a datatable that allows the user to update the status to **NG** or **COMPLETED**, default is dash (-) sign. If completed is selected for the row, it is hidden, but if NG it will just change the row color to red. I have already achieved the functionality. My one problem is if I'm using the filter (filter is **SHOW COMPLETED** or **SHOW NG**), the newly updated status row is not included in displaying in the data table. Here's what I do to update the status of the row.

```
//selected-status is the rows' drop down element id
$(document).on('change','.selected-status', function(){
    let id = $(this).parents('tr').find('.updateStatus').val();
    let selected_status = $(this).val();
    let dis = this;
    //status is updated in DB
    $.post('/user/guest/list/updateStatus', {
        selected_status: selected_status,
        id: id,
        _token: $("[name=csrf-token]").attr('content'),
    }, function (data) {
        if (data.name === "") {
            console.log('Not found')
        } else {
            if (selected_status == 2) { //if NG
                $(dis).parents('tr').css('background-color', '#f7b9b5')
            } else if(selected_status == 0) { //if default
                $(dis).parents('tr').css('background-color', ' white')
            }else{ //if completed
                $(dis).parents('tr').remove();
                var tr = $(dis).closest('tr');
                var row = guestTable.row( tr );
            }
        }
    }).fail(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
})
```

This is the filter code:

```
$(document).on('change','.changeDisplayGuestListTable', function(){
    let status = $(".by-status").val();

    guestTable
        .search( '' )
        .columns().search( '' )
        .draw();
    //default filter , show NG status and no status (dash sign)
    if(status == 0){
        guestTable
        .column(11).search("0|2",true, false).draw();
    }else{
        if(status == 1){
            guestTable
            .column(11).search("1").draw();
        }else if(status == 2){
            guestTable
            .column(11).search("2").draw();
        }
    }

});
```

This is now the part that the newly updated rows are not included in displaying in the filter. Any help?

Comment: Can you add your code in a jsfiddle.net or a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from the code, datatables uses a value that a specific column holds as the means for filtering. Column 11 it seems, so the 12th column if it’s a 0 index.  Here, although the post request you’re sending presumably updates the entry in the backend, it doesn’t affect the table itself until you’ve refreshed. Currently, in you’re callback, you’re updating the color of the rows but not the value for the status itself. As such, that won’t change until the page refreshes. You’ll need to update that value in column 11 for the selected row as well so that the query recognizes the row as having the value it’s searching for.

Comment: Yes that's the idea. How can I update the value of the row?

Comment: As you already have access to the row through jQuery, which is how you’re updating it’s color, you just need to find the appropriate column and update the appropriate attribute. I’m assuming that’s it’s val, so you’d need to do yourColumnObject.val(someVal), where yourColumnObject is something I leave to you to find, to set its value to someVal. I’m assuming here that’s as simple as going yourRowObject.find(‘td’)[11].val(someVal), or some such. I’d suggest taking a quick look into jQuery selectors to understand how that’s working.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Hello. I have found some fiddle that does have almost the same logic with what I have but I can't make it work. https://jsfiddle.net/jebwq9yL/1/ , if you can help me figure it out. Thank you.